# Definition of an inline value

Tags: assembly, definition, inline-code

When browsing through the [x86 Assembly Language Reference Manual](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/817-5477/817-5477.pdf), I came across this definition of an *immediate operand*:

> Operands can be immediate (that is, constant expressions that evaluate to an inline value), [...]

If I got it correctly, an expression returns a value. Does a *constant* expression then return a constant value? Does *inline* value mean that it will be substituted by some other value after having undergone the process of assembly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just means that the expression must be a value that can be calculated during assembly. Examples of constant expressions include:

```
5
5+5
5*5
MyConstant  (where this constant is defined somewhere else)
MyConstant*4
```

Values for all above can be determined by the assembler and substituted with the value of the expression.

In contrast, non-constant expressions have values that cannot be determined during assembly. Examples include:

```
ah     (a register)
ah*al  (expression containing registers)
[0x800] (a memory location)
```

Comment: Would you mind telling me what the actual meaning of "inline" in the context of assembly languages is?

Comment: @MaxHerrmann I have not seen the word inline used in assembly manuals, but here it seems to just mean "a constant value". Note that `mov eax, 1+2` and `mov eax, 1+1+1` and other variants of constant expressions returning 3 all assemble into simply `mov eax, 3`. I.e. they are expressions that are evaluated by the assembler.

Answer (score 5):

> Does a constant expression then return a constant value?

Yes. An immediate operand creates a constant value in an opcode. Like `mov eax, 3` creates an opcode consisting of several bytes - according to [x32/x64 Intel Manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html).

```
B0+ rb ib MOV r8, imm8 OI Valid Valid Move imm8 to r8.
B8+ rw iw MOV r16, imm16 OI Valid Valid Move imm16 to r16.
B8+ rd id MOV r32, imm32 OI Valid Valid Move imm32 to r32.
C6 /0 ib MOV r/m8, imm8 MI Valid Valid Move imm8 to r/m8.
C7 /0 iw MOV r/m16, imm16 MI Valid Valid Move imm16 to r/m16.
C7 /0 id MOV r/m32, imm32 MI Valid Valid Move imm32 to r/m32.
```

For example: For 32-bit-mode the following byte combinations do represent the valid opcodes. This means for `mov destination, 3` there are several possibilities:

```
   b0 03                   mov    al, 3
66 b8 03 00                mov    ax, 3
   b8 03 00 00 00          mov    eax, 3
   c6 45 00 03             mov    byte  ptr [xxx], 3
66 c7 45 00 03 00          mov    word  ptr [xxx], 3
   c7 45 00 03 00 00 00    mov    dword ptr [xxx], 3
```

B0h and B8h represent a one-byte opcode, C6h and C7h represent a two-byte opcode consisting of an opcode byte and a Mod/RM-byte coding the addressing mode - in this case `indirect addressing`. `66h` designates an `Operand-Size Prefix` indicating that the following instruction uses an 16-bit(out-of-address-mode) operand - an exception compared to the normal 32-bit mode operand. An 8-bit operand is encoded with another opcode. The remaining bytes are the encoding of a 8/16/32-bit value of `3`.

> Does inline value mean that it will be substituted by some other value after having undergone the process of assembly?

No. Assembl(y|ing) is the process of incorporating constant values into resulting opcodes(seqeunces of bytes). In a way, everything is inline in assembly.